# Publishing SQL Server database in Access to Sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sharepoint, ms-access-2010

In my project I need to publish an Access database into Sharepoint. I need to add a web form into it. Is it possible to add a WebForm that can be shown in the Sharepoint site, using ODBC(Database from SQL server on local machine)?

I can connect to that database and edit records in it. But I can't make a form with that web icon on it. Is that even possible to publish something from Access to Sharepoint using local SQL server and make a form to show data from it?

Comment: Good question, but what do you mean by *local* SQL Server ? A SQL Server on the same LAN as the SP ?

Comment: yes, it's in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert and can't test my ideas, but I read that if you publish an Access db with Access tables to SP, Access tables will be converted to a SQL Server table by SP. Perhaps you could then delete or rename the SP created table on SP's SQL Server and create a view with the same name which points to you table on the other server ?
Have a look at the SP site: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/104005

Answer (score 0):

I found something like that:

> I totally missed the fact that this was a web app. Access web apps
>   work with SharePoint, no other data source.   That's true for Access
>   2010.  But in Access 2013, there is a hybrid solution possible:  Access Client + Access Web + SQL Server.  It's still very new and not
>   common yet, and unfortunately there isn't a migration path from Access
>   2010 web forms to Access 2013 web forms. You have to build the web app
>   from scratch.  But it's a better platform than Access 2010 offered.

that means i should use access 2013 ?

Comment: Obviously. But that requires a different versions of SP ! You need coherence: Access 2013 and SP 2013

Comment: and the question is how to use that SQL server there?

Comment: I think it is n my reply. When you create a web app, you create Access tables. When you upload the app to SP, these Access tables are transformed into Sql tables automagically. THe more difficult point is to have your Access web app use existing tables on another SS.

Comment: but i need to use exisitng SQL tables with large data in that access app.